# Redirect from client component in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a project using Next.js 13, and I have a scenario where I'm trying to call a client-side component from a server-side page. Once that client-side component, DeleteAddressAlertDialog, interacts with my API through a "use server" component and successfully deletes an address, I want to redirect to the settings page. Here's my code structure:

page.tsx

```
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { id: number } }) {
  // ...
  <div className="flex justify-end mt-8">
    <DeleteAddressAlertDialog contactId={contactId} addressId={params.id} />
  </div>
  // ...
}
```

DeleteAddressAlertDialog.tsx:

```
    function DeleteAddressAlertDialog({ contactId, addressId }: {
      contactId: number,
      addressId: number
    }) {
      async function handleDelete(contactId: number, addressId: number) {
        try {
          await deleteAddress(contactId, addressId) 
 // Should now redirect to the settings page after successful deletion
        } catch (e: any) {
          console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
      }
    }
```

handler.tsx:

```
"use server"
async function deleteAddress(contactId: number, addressId: number) {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.BASE_API_URL + "/addresses/" + addressId, {
    cache: "no-cache",
    method: "DELETE"
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong")
  }
}
```

My question is: How can I implement the redirection to the settings page after successfully deleting an address in this scenario? What is the recommended way to handle redirection after an asynchronous action in a Next.js project with this setup?

I have tried `redirect('/settings')` which gives me an error: `NEXT_REDIRECT` and

```
 const router = useRouter()
    router.push("/settings")
```

which states that it is an invalid hook call.

Comment: Have you received any data when successfully deleting an address?

Comment: Yes, deleting an address works without any problems. But forwarding afterwards is not possible. I have the same problem described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect (on the subpage under example)

Comment: It works fine under the main page: export default async function Page({params}: { params: { id: number } }) {
but redirection within a component seems not to be possible (inside of DeleteAddressAlertDialog). It throws: NEXT_REDIRECT

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second method to redirect. But just move the `useRouter()` hook call outside of the `handleDelete` function as hooks should be called directly inside the react functional components.

```js
function DeleteAddressAlertDialog({
  contactId,
  addressId
}: {
  contactId: number,
  addressId: number
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  async function handleDelete(contactId: number, addressId: number) {
    try {
      await deleteAddress(contactId, addressId)
      router.push("/settings");
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I was on the right track but the solution was to import from next/navigation instead of next/router

Comment: @hantoren if that solves the problem, please [mark this answer as solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).